# Fetching the Opportunities Id from a list of Opportunities name

Tags: business-logic

Fetching the Opportunities Id from a list of Opportunities name.

I have an asset list through which i am creating opportunities. However at the end i require a map of which contains the key as Opportunities Id and values as corresponding Asset Id. ( Each Opportunity has exactly one Asset mapped as a linked asset for which the opportunity is created.

```
                Map<Id,Id> OpportunitryAsset = new Map<Id,Id>
                List<Opportunity> createOpportunity = new List<Opportunity>();
                for (Asset astList: assetList )
                {
                    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
                    Opp.OwnerId = astList.LastModifiedById;
                    opp.Name = astlist.Name + ' Replacement Opportunity';
                    opp.AccountId = astList.AccountId;
                    opp.CloseDate = (system.TODAY() + 30);
                    opp.StageName = 'Identify';
                    opp.Business_Type__c = 'Replacement'
                    createOpportunity.add(opp); 
                    OpportunityAsset.put(opp.Name,astList.Id);
                    
                }
                
                insert createOpportunity;
```

Is there any method by which we could create a map that contains the Id's of the Opportunities as a key and Id of the Assets as a value.
I tried using a nested for loop but not getting the required map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have inserted the opportunities. You need to do a for-loop and build your map. Here is a sample based on your example. Since assetList and createOpportunity are both a list which are of the same size and data are being built upon same index, we can use it as below.

```
Map<Id, Asset> assetMap = new Map<Id, Asset>();    
For(integer i = 0; i < assetList.size(); i++) {
    assetMap.put(createOpportunity[i].Id, assetList[i]);
}
```

Comment: you should point out that OP makes an assumption that an Opportunity has at most 1 asset; a better map is `Map<Id,Asset[]> assetsByOppoId`